# Upload file error in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2, laravel-ioc

I use laravelUploader package form [this link](https://github.com/pricecurrent/LaravelUploader) for upload my files
. when i use this package to send file in lumen with below code :

```
$file = $this->uploader->file($request->file('file'))->push(storage_path('app'));
return $this->respondCreated(['data'=>$file->getFullPath()]);
```

i got an error like :

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 752:
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory] is not instantiable while building [Almazik\LaravelUploader\LaravelUploader].
```

now how can i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind implementation of `Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory` using this snippets.

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory::class,
    function ($app) {
        return new Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager($app);
    }
);
```

> **Note:** You can do this in your `bootstrap/app.php` file right after you register `Almazik\LaravelUploader\FileUploaderServiceProvider`.

Comment: excellent response, works great with lumen 5.3, no longer using loadComponent() to do this properly

Comment: Glad to help you, sir.